# Automatic JSON decoding using the Flask test_client()

Tags: python, flask

When testing using Flask's built in [test_client](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/api/#flask.Flask.test_client), I have found there is no way to automatically decode a JSON response.

Some pytest code I have for testing the signin process is:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('user_info', [sign_in])
def test_sign_in_post(self, user_info, client):
    r = client.post(
        f'/{ApiConfig.name}/sign_in',
        data=json.dumps(user_info),
        content_type='application/json',
    )
    assert r.status_code == 200
    assert 'session_key' in json.loads(r.data.decode())
```

The part I'm asking about is the `json.loads(r.data.decode())` snippet. Is there a better way to do this?

In the `requests` module, for example, the code would be `assert 'session_key' in r.json()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that Flask 1.0 is released, the response object has a `json` attribute and a `get_json` method just like `request`:

```
resp = client.get('/api/users/)
print(resp.json)
```

Previously, you had to load it yourself:

```
from flask import json

rv = client.get('/api/users')
json.loads(rv.get_data(as_text=True))
```